# How to boot into different partition?

Tags: 14.04, grub2, partitioning, system-installation, grubrescue

This arises from trying to upgrade to 14.04 from 12.04. The upgrade failed, so that when I tried to reboot I got an `error: file not found` message and the grub rescue prompt.
(Up to that point, everything had gone fine.) After a number of failed attempts to fix the situation from there, I reinstalled 14.04 to a new small partition. I can see the old volume and mount it, but since it has a year's worth of programs and configuration in it what I'd really like to do is just change things so that it boots into it in the first place. I have two drives, `sda1` which is the older volume, and `sdb1` which is a second drive for data. The new partition, now mounted at `/` when I boot up, is `sda6`.  I want `sda1` to mount at `/`, or otherwise for it to be the `home` partition.

How do I do this?

Comment: Well, the old system wouldn't boot the new install of 14.04, so what makes you think it will now?

Comment: @mikewhatever I have a lot more power to (easily) modify relevant files, etc. now that there is at least one working distro on the machine, than I did from grub rescue.  So even if the same error arises when I do boot into sda1 I will be in a better position to identify its cause and fix it.

Comment: Matt, did Grub of the new install pick up the old one? If not, you might want to run `sudo update-grub`. Marty, why don't you post something helpful then?

Comment: @mikewhatever It doesn't, i.e it doesn't provide options like I've seen in prior dual-boot scenarios I've been in.  I just ran `update-grub` and it says 'Found Ubuntu 14.04.1 ... on /dev/sda1' as well as /dev/sdb1.  So I'm going to reboot now and see what happens...

Comment: @mikewhatever Well, unless there's a key I need to press at some point during the boot process to bring up grub options, nothing has changed.  It just goes right to the new partition.

Comment: Try the Shift key right after the BIOS screen.

Comment: @mikewhatever Nope, that didn't do anything.  I note that `grub` per se isn't installed--and if I try to install it, I'm informed that other packages such as grub-pc and grub2-common will be removed.  Do these represent newer versions?

Comment: Yep, probably. These are the packages installed by default. What can I say, this site isn't really suited for a troubleshooting back and forth exchange. There is nowhere to post outputs, and the comments section get long fast. Try posting a thread at ubuntuforums.org instead of here.

Comment: @mikewhatever See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I went into `/etc/default/grub` and uncommented the line

```
GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

and it worked.  That is, on bootup I got and old-school list of possible boot options, and I was able to choose my old partition (sda1).  It booted into that partition without any error, so far.  So it appears that for whatever reason, my configuration did not like the graphical terminal.